# Crash in GL.DrawElement()

Tags: opengl, vbo, opentk

When I try to draw a scene using `GL.DrawArrays()` the code runs successfully, but crashes when I use `GL.DrawElements()`.

The input paramaters and data is valid.

Comment: What is "crash"? Do you use debugger? Error checking? Any messages?

Comment: Do you provide some kind of index list via an element array buffer?

Comment: Sounds like a pinning issue; you may need to tell the .NET GC not to move the managed memory being used with those functions.

Comment: I'd start with dropping "The input paramaters and data is valid." assumption. If it is valid and driver isn't screwed up - which is very very likely because everyone using this function, it just can't be bugged - this surely would work just fine.

Comment: This error almost always means that you're reading far outside the bounds of one of your buffers. Your input parameters and/or data is not valid. Post some actual code so that we can see what's going wrong where.